# como asignar una variable al output de html2pdf

Tags: php, html2pdf

buen dia, tengo un pequeño problema para generar mi archivo pdf con html2pdf, ps bien el sistema logra generar mi arcivo perfectamente, pero quiero asignarle una variable al output en el nombre y me arroja error con el codigo que intente, ejemplo si quisiera que al momento de descargarlo me pararezca el id del campo pero no me muestra nada

```html
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resustado)) {
  $paquete = $row['paquete'];
  $tamano_book = $row['tamano_book'];
  $evento = $row['tipo'];
  $cant_foto = $row['cant_act_foto'];
  $cant_video = $row['cant_act_video'];
  $institucion = $row['nom_inst']; 
  $titulo = $evenrto."/".$institucion."-".date('Y');
  if ($cant_foto>0) {
   
   $foto = 'foto';
  }
  if ($cant_video>0) {
   $video = 'video';
  }
 }
}
}
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

if (isset($_POST['crear'])) {

 ob_start();
 require_once 'historial.php';
 $html = ob_get_clean();

 $html2 = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'es', 'true', 'UTF-8');

 $html2->writeHTML($html);
 $html2->output({$titulo}'.pdf');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

creo que tienes un error aqui: `$evenrto` deberia ser `$evento` ?

```
$titulo = $evenrto."/".$institucion."-".date('Y');
```

finalmente:

```
$html2->output("{$titulo}.pdf");
```

funcionara si la variable $titulo tiene un valor asignado